# List and page structure for rating tracker?

Tags: list, web-part, custom-list

I'm just getting started in SharePoint, and I'm confused on how to reach the end result.

Ultimately, I'd like to have a page where a user can enter new rows.  These rows would have the following fields:

1. Region
2. Market
3. Category
4. Toolkit
5. Rating
6. Comments

In my mind, these fields possible values would be driven by lists that I have setup already.

For instance, the Region list includes 5 regions.  The Market list includes all the markets which are mapped, using a lookup, to regions from the Region list.  The Category list is simply a list of five categories. The Rating list is a list of rating values (0-5), mapped to a comment prompt.

So when a user selects a Region from a `dropdown`, that result cascades into the Market `dropdown`, where only markets from the selected region are displayed.  The user can then select a value from the Category `dropdown`, similarly with the Toolkit and the Rating (all driven from simple lists)

How do I accomplish this functionality?  It seems like it should be simple, but SharePoint seems very complex for a beginner.  Is there a specific Web Part I should be using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cascading values is not supported out of the box. You will need to use something custom, check out http://spservices.codeplex.com/, open sourced library which has cascading capabilities.

HTH

Comment: Or via InfoPath

Comment: True, you could in InfoPath.